# Spreadsheet for iPad

Tags: ipad, spreadsheet

I need to have a spreadsheet like app for iPad. I need to generate the grid for the spreadsheet which should be very smooth.

I used UILabel and UIView for each cell of the grid, but it is very heavy.

Which component will be suitable for generating the grid?

The columns and rows of the grid should be resizable.

Thiagesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success with [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) for creating a spreadsheet like interface.

Comment: I used AQGridView but it is not suitable for lrge number of dta.